# How to change passphrase of Debian encrypted partition?

Tags: debian, encryption

After using an encrypted partition with Debian Luks for some time, now the correct passphrase is no longer accepted.
How to change to a new passphrase ?
Do I need to encrypt the partition again?
I have backup of the data in the encrypted partion, so I don't mind losing it.

Comment: well, to start, why is it your existing password is no longer accepted? do you believe the volume has been damaged and thus can't verify it, or the disk mechanically damaged, or is it that the password was already changed by another party? I think that is the crux of the issue.  If your password is actually not currently valid, then you have little hope of recovering the data, whereas if the volume has been damaged, and you'll likely not get in, why would you want to continue to use it, and not replace it with a clean one? if the disk is unsound, of course replacing it is the only option.

Comment: Frank's right. And you can't add / change a passphrase without knowing a current working passphrase. Tried a header backup, running  from a live iso? Or `cryptsetup -v isLuks /dev/theDevice`